# How to do many to many in active model serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm looking for a solution to use many to many association in active model serializer.

Let's say I have a user with many user types through a many to many table, how can I return the user types for a specific user?

Do I need to create a serializer for the many to many model?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty stupid. I had set the serializer to "`has_one user_type`", a simple change to "`has_many user_types`" worked.